# Create a factory function that returns an object with immutable state

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, state, immutability, factory

Link to CodePen https://codepen.io/jaspercreel/pen/Mvaodp

Basically, my function will look something like this:

```
const Factory = (args) => {

  const state = {
    args
  }

  const methods = {  

    getState() => {
      return args;
    },

    setState(args) => {
      state.args = args;
    },

    doStuffWithState() => {
      let args = this.getState();
      function(args) {
        return args plus something else;
      }();
    }

  }

  return Object.assign({}, methods);

}
```

The problem is that whenever I call doStuffWithState() it changes the state object. I thought I would be safe creating a new variable with the returned state, but I learned that when referencing an object you are only creating a new reference. So my question is this, how can I create immutable state that can be referenced but not changed (except by helper functions) in a factory function?

My end goal is to create a sorter factory function that will create an object that takes arrays and sorts and searches them in different ways. I want to be able to store a default array in the sorter that can be referenced to return different sorting options but not changed. Any advice?

Comment: _"So my question is this, how can I create immutable state that can be referenced but not changed (except by helper functions)"_ , _"I want to be able to store a default array in the sorter that can be referenced to return different sorting options but not changed."_ How can an object be both immutable and capable of being changed at the same time? Is requirement to change the original object, or copy the original object and change the copy of the object?

Comment: I want to return a value stored in an object and work with that value alone, not on the object itself. This can be done easily, but it seems like it can't be done in my factory function and I don't know why

Comment: What is the purpose of storing the value within an object?

Comment: I guess there isn't one, however extracting it to a variable only gives me the same result. I can't seem to create an immutable anything. You can follow my codepen link to see it in action. I call a set state helper function. then call a get state helper function, then work on the returned value and it modifies the state whether it is in an object or not. very confusing.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding about what an object is and what a value is... it's both the same. The object is the value of a reference. Maybe this is the reason why you don't see any difference.

Comment: If you really want an immutable object you could use `Object.freeze(obj)`. After doing so any attempt to change something in `obj` will result in an error.

Comment: You could deep clone the state and freeze the new one. However, **cloning is hard**.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to store the JavaScript object as a `JSON` string with `JSON.stringify()` and use `JSON.parse()` to parse the `JSON` string to a JavaScript object, which does not reference the original object passed that is stored as a string.

You can also utilize `Promise` to return a JavaScript object reflecting properties of `JSON` string, passed to `Object.assign()`, which can return modified properties or values of original object, without affecting original object passed to `Factory`, which returns a `Promise` value as the `JSON` string format of the original passed object.

```js
// `const` declaration cannot be changed or deleted
const Factory = (args) => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(args));

const state = Factory({
  abc: [1, 2, 3]
});

state.then(data => console.log(data)); // `{"abc":[1,2,3]}`

// change object passed to `Factory`
state.then(data => Object.assign(JSON.parse(data), {
    abc: JSON.parse(data).abc.concat(4, 5, 6)
}))
// do stuff with modified `JSON` `args` as JavaScript object
.then(res => {console.log(res); return res}) // `{"abc":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}`
.then(res =>
  // `res` : `{"abc":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}`
  // `state` `Promise` value is original object 
  // as valid `JSON` `{"abc":[1,2,3]}`
  // return original `args` as `JSON` string
  state.then(data => {console.log(res, data); return data})
)
// original `args` as JavaScript object
.then(o => console.log(JSON.parse(o)))
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use promises. There's nothing asnchronous here

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all the answers and comments guys. It turns out I was being very dumb. So in my tests I was sometimes able to return a value without altering the original and sometimes not, and I could not figure out why. Now I know it is because in my tests that altered the state, I was calling sort() on an array, and sort is an in-place function. It alters the original array.

Such a small oversight on my part, but I consider it a learning experience. Thanks again for the effort in the help guys. Hopefully my dumb mistake can be a learning experience for others too.